# how to flush cache immediately with Ehcache after specific properties of Element are updated?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I'm asked to introduce Cache to DAO layer to reduce readings/writings to database, in the meanwhile, we want to apply the strategy to immediately flush cache after *specific* properties are updated.

We're using clusters, the database is internally synchronized among clusters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a lot more details is you want a technical answer. A quick way to get caching is using something like spring-cache annotations.

What do you mean by flushing? You mean evicting from the cache? This can be done by asking the cache to evict a given entry.